# Файл не видит переменную из другого файла PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Файл signup.php не видит переменную $connect из файла connect.php. Использую PHP 7.1

```
File: connect.php
<?php
    $connect = new mysqli(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    'root',
    'usersinfo');
?>
```

```
File: signup.php
<?php
require_once ('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $secondName = $_POST['secondName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_check = $_POST['password_check'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
}

if ($password === $password_check) {
    $result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `usersinfo` (`id`, `firstName`, `secondName`, `email`, `telephone`, `login`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'firstName', 'secondName', 'email', 'telephone', 'login', 'password')");
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Регистрация прошла успешно';
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
    header('Location: register.php');
}
if ($result) {
    print ('Успешно');
}
```

Comment: Покажите какая у вас там ошибка выходит

Comment: В вашем примере `if (isset($_PO**S**T['register'])) {` пропущена буква

Comment: ZxNuClear, спасибо, пропущенную букву исправил.

Comment: YaMus, ошибка: Undefined variable '$connect'

Comment: connect.php и signup.php находятся в одной директории?

Comment: YaMus, да, находятся в одной директории.

Comment: Проверил ваш код, все работает. Покажите полный код что у вас там?

Comment: YaMus, нашёл ошибку в другом, код работает, но всё равно переменная подчёркивается красным.